# vue3 and stylelint ,how to fix --Unexpected unknown pseudo-class selector,":deep"

Tags: vuejs3

I config stylelintrc.js like this:

```
rules: {
    "selector-pseudo-element-no-unknown": [true, {
      "ignorePseudoClasses": ["deep",""]
    }]
  }
```

but not ok, my vue file is here
[image: link]

the error is:

> Unexpected unknown pseudo-class selector selector-pseudo-class-no-unknown
> ":deep"

the error image is here
[image: link]

Comment: Please do not post code as images... (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 12):

[image: add ignorePseudoClasses sub rule]

If this problem occurs, you can simply modify the rules in [stylelint.config.js]:

add ignorePseudoClasses rule item naming [deep]

Answer (score 4):

this can work

```
'selector-pseudo-class-no-unknown': [
     true,
     {
         ignorePseudoClasses: ['deep'],
     },
],
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configure/) Stylelint uses cosmiconfig to find and load your configuration object. And there is defined sequence where it is going to search for your config.
In my project I had both a `stylelint` property in `package.json` and as well a `.stylelintrc` file. When I added rule to `package.json` file which has higher priority everything started to work as it should.